# Show shopping cart price rules line by line

Tags: php, magento, rules, discount

I have 2 shopping cart rules in my store and its showing in a single line which leads to confusion. See the below image.

[image]

But I would like to show the two rules `5% Discount` and `10% Discount` to be shown in separate lines, like

> Subtotal     -Rs xx.xx
>   5% Discount -Rs xx.xx
>   10% Discount -Rs xx.xx
>   Tax-Rs xx.xx
>   Grand Total  -Rs xx.xx.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: What does your current code look like? In it's current form, there's no way to tell how you should fix it.

Comment: I thought everyone who does have two discounts would have faced this issue. That is why I simply shows the image

Comment: enable the template path hints to locate the file from where it is displayed